# About って in the following sentences

Tags: grammar, usage, nuances, て-form

って has many meanings in spoken Japanese. Although I have looked it up in the dictionary, I am still confused about it. Please tell me the following usage.

> ①いいかげんに早く寝なさい**だって**(please tell me the combination of だって)
>
> ②困ったわねえ**だって**さ(this sentence makes no sense to me)
>
> ③ない、ない、ないです**って**(when someone is    denying something)
>
> ④そんなこと知ってる**って**(I think here it is contracted form of と思う

Answer (score 2):

The first and the second examples are reporting what someone else said. i.e "S/he told/said ...".

The third one is repeating what the opponent has just said, like "Huh? You said no, no and no?"

The forth one is complaining about how you have to bother to say it. i.e "I know it, I'm telling you!".